# did + present-continuous form

Tags: tense, grammaticality

A conversation between me and my friend:

Friend: I was sleeping when you called. And I do that everyday till 13:00.

Me: ok

~3 days later he replies to me at 10:00 already~

Now my question: Is it grammatically correct, if I say: “I thought you did sleeping everyday till 13:00!?” instead of “I thought you used to sleep till 13:00!?” / “I thought you slept till 13:00”

---

P.s Would be grateful if you correct any (english/grammatical etc.) mistake(s) in the question-text itself too! :)

Answer (score 0):

> I thought you did sleeping everyday till 13:00.

This is grammatically incorrect. We usually don't use `do + V-ing`.

> I thought you used to sleep till 13:00.

This is grammatically correct. However, "used to" here changes the meaning, and I think it doesn't correctly reflect what you want to say here. When you use `used to`, you're talking about a habit *in the past* that is no longer true in the present. (look up how to use `used to` for more information)

> I thought you slept till 13:00.

This is grammatically correct. However, note that you're using "slept", which means you're talking about the past. If you want to talk about an on-going habit, use the `present simple` tense. By using `simple past` (slept), you're saying that your friend didn't sleep till 13:00 *in the past* (only at the time where they said "I do that everyday till 13:00").

Corrections:

> I thought you *sleep* till 13:00.

This would be the correct form of your 3rd  example. By using "sleep" (`present simple`), you're talking about something your friend does habitually everyday.

> I thought you *said* (that) you sleep till 13:00.

This is another possible response. While the correction before means "I thought it was true that you sleep till 13:00", this version means "I thought you were telling me that. Did you lie?". (It doesn't have to mean "Did you lie?" but can also mean "You're not doing as you said".) This version questions their *statement* instead of the action of "sleep till 13:00".

Comment: And how about “I thought you (said you) ‘do sleeping’ till 13:00?”

Comment: That doesn't work. "Do sleeping" probably wouldn't make sense anywhere.

Comment: I agree with what you wrote except for one thing - I find “I thought you sleep..." and "I thought you slept…” equally acceptable in this context. Actually I think I’d be slightly more likely to say the latter. Once you’re talking about the past, it's common for a verb to be in the past tense even if the action/state is still ongoing - it doesn't mean the situation no longer holds. For example: "He asked me for a donation because he knew I was generous" - that doesn't imply at all that I'm no longer generous.

Comment: There are a few exception to that first rule, although it is generally true.  For example where the gerund (-ing) form is a pastime.  "I do cooking" is a relatively common way to say you do cooking as a hobby, similarly with swimming, cycling, painting, knitting, rowing, sailing, etc.  But sleeping is not a pastime - at least not normally!!!